# Laravel 5.2 Login With Condition

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

So, I have users table which is default by laravel. But I add a new column named 'status'. 

So the columns on the users table are id, name, email, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at, status

The status values are between 0 and 1. 1 for admin, and 0 for regular user.

Also I have auth, but the problem is how can I check if users' status is 0 or 1 when login so that I can redirect it according to their status? -- admin will go to admin panel and user will go to home

User default by laravel with addition 'status'

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password', 'status',
        ];
        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];
    }
```

HomeController also default by laravel

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

LoginController also default by laravel

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

THANKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `authenticated()` method in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` to add logic after the user is authenticated:

```
   protected function authenticated($request,$user)
    {
        if(\Auth::user()->status){
            return redirect('/admin'); 
        }

        return redirect('/home');   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If its all default laravel authentication then you should be able to do

```
( Auth::user()->status === 0 ) ? 'do something' : 'do something else';
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, The laravel redirect to "authenticated" function after login. So you can add "authenticated" function in "LoginController". In the "authenticated" function will get the user object.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (!$user->status == 1) {
        return redirect('admin');
    }
    return redirect('web');
}
```

Comment: almost at the same time :-)